# npm build failed: ERROR in Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ng-packagr

I'm trying to **build** my angular5 proj but it fails.

This is an excerpt of **deps tree**:

[simple-kaishi](https://github.com/fabioformosa/simple-kaishi) <- [kaishi](https://github.com/fabioformosa/kaishi) <- [ngx-admin-lte](https://github.com/TwanoO67/ngx-admin-lte)

[ngx-admin-lte](https://github.com/TwanoO67/ngx-admin-lte): (develop branch) is the angular version of popular adminlte theme

[kaishi](https://github.com/fabioformosa/kaishi) : (master branch) is a my core-library that includes ngx-admin-lte and adds other core features.

[simple-kaishi](https://github.com/fabioformosa/simple-kaishi) : (master branch) is my sample project that includes kaishi

**To reproduce**:

1. clone [kaishi](https://github.com/fabioformosa/kaishi)
2. kaishi> `npm install`
3. kaishi> `npm run packagr`to package kaishi as a feature library
4. clone [simple-kaishi](https://github.com/fabioformosa/simple-kaishi)
5. simple-kaishi> `npm install`
6. simple-kaishi> `npm link ../kaishi/dist`
7. simple-kaishi> `npm start` it should be ok
8. simple-kaishi> `npm run build` build fails!

**Build error is**

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module
>       'NgxAdminLteModule in /git/simple-kaishi/node_modules/kaishi/node_modules/ngx-admin-lte/ngx-admin-lte.d.ts'

What's the matter?

-- details --

my `ng -- version`

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
```

**+++ UPDATE +++**

I've noticed that problem arises for `ng build --prod` but not for `ng build`.
My proj structure is not the cause, but the cause is around the external lib `ngx-admin-lte`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it!

Problem was in AOT compiling option. Indeed, `npm run build` launches `ng --prod` that's a shortcut for `--AOT=true`.  [ngx-admin-lte](https://github.com/TwanoO67/ngx-admin-lte) lib had a bug.

This [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831#issuecomment-303615816) helped me to solve. In main ts file, it needs to replace all following imports like this:
`import { LogoComponent } from './widgets/logo'`
with:
`import { LogoComponent } from './widgets/logo.component'`

I've pushed a PR to ngx-admin-lte and Library has been fixed.
My project structure is OK.
If this can be useful, looking for AOT compiler problem if you get an error similar to this.